# Seeking libusb_device tutorial and/or examples

Tags: delphi, libusb

Like the title says (for Delphi 7). It seems that GINMF (google is not my friend)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Thanks in advance

---

Update: Delphi only, please, not just the generic pages which I can find by googling. Thanks

Comment: What device class in particular do you need to talk to?  I am aware of Delphi HID class components, for example.  I'm not aware of much generic stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delphi USB Package: [USBLibExport](http://en.pudn.com/downloads171/sourcecode/delphi_control/detail792576_en.html) if you want to develop USB applications

[Direct link](http://ynlmns.home.xs4all.nl/)

Comment: I have downlaoded it and am looking into it. I will get back to you

Comment: Curious is better than furious :-)  Sorry, I got side-tracked into somethign else. However, I will update this question for future reference just as soon as I have looked into it.  Thanks for your sugegstion. Have you used it yourself?

Comment: LOL, I haven't used it yet. The question was more for future reference.

Comment: +1 Sorry to say, it just got de-prioritized ...  I will post here when I try it.